# Iterating sublists without using the list length

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have a list of things, and I need to apply some processing on successive (and overlapping) groups of 3 elements:

I can do it with:

```py
for i in range(len(things)-2):
    process(things[i:i+3])
```

So for instance:

```
things=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

And I want to process:

```
[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7]
```

But is there a clever (but readable) way to do it without explicitly using `len(things)`?

Comment: Can you show some sample input & expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you're looking for is called a *sliding/moving* window. There are different ways to achieve this but the easiest is to use `tee()` and `islice()` functions from `itertools`. Using this you can define a `window()` function like below with default window size of 2.

```
import itertools

def window(iterable, n=2):
    iters = itertools.tee(iterable, n)
    for i, it in enumerate(iters):
        next(itertools.islice(it, i, i), None)
    return zip(*iters)
```

Then you can use it as

```
>>> things=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> list(window(things, n = 3))
[(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7)]
>>> for elem in window(things, n = 3):
...     print(elem)
... 
(0, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 4)
(3, 4, 5)
(4, 5, 6)
(5, 6, 7)
```

**Edit**: For one time use a more simpler option may be

```
>>> list(zip(things, things[1:], things[2:]))
[(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7)]
```

Comment: A bit of overkill since I only need this once in the code, but take my upvote :)

Comment: @xenoid You can just use something like `zip(things, things[1:], things[2:])` for one time use. I have edited the post to show the results.

Comment: @SigmalEpsilon This is indeed something your solution made me think about, plus I have special processing at both ends that can be nicely achieved by adding the adequate bits to the three lists. My only worry is that this copies the lists (which IRL are going to be 100 to 1000 elements). At least this spares me writing my own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it could be:

```
for i in things[0:-2]:
    a=things.index(i)
    process(things[a:a+3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try using `enumerate`, Here `len(things[i : i+len_]) == len_` is to drop uneven sized list that get's accumulated at the end iterations.

```
len_ = 3

[things[i : i+len_] for i, j in enumerate(things) if len(things[i : i+len_]) == len_]

[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7]]
```

---

```
len_ = 4

[things[i : i+len_] for i, j in enumerate(things) if len(things[i : i+len_]) == len_]

[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```